# Transitive dependency version is altered by dependencyManagement

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am experiencing an issue in which a dependency within dependencyManagement appears to be overriding another dependency's transitive versions. I've included a simple pom file below with a requireUpperBounds rule to demonstrate the issue. Running `mvn install` with the pom results in multiple occurrences of the following error:

```
Require upper bound dependencies error for io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:2.0.2 [runtime] paths to dependency are:
+-com.blah:blah:1
  +-io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-vavr:2.1.0
    +-io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:2.0.2 [runtime] (managed) <-- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:2.1.0 [runtime]
```

Maven tries to pull in resilience4j-ratelimiter v2.0.2 rather than the version specified in the pom file (v2.1.0). This does not occur when I remove the spring-cloud-dependencies dependency from the dependencyManagement section or remove its scope. The spring-cloud-dependencies pom does not mention resilience4j or '2.0.2', so I am not sure where that version is coming from.

Additionally, the maven documentation for dependencyManagement states that

> the
> version and other values from this section are used for that dependency **if they were not
> already specified.**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.blah</groupId>
    <artifactId>blah</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <resilience4j.version>2.1.0</resilience4j.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-dependency-checks</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireUpperBoundDeps/>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-vavr</artifactId>
            <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this might be happening?

EDIT:
Based on the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), it appears that adding a dependency with `<scope>import</scope>` and `<type>pom</type>` in the dependencyManagement section will effectively add that dependency's pom as a parent. The spring-cloud-dependencies pom references multiple other pom's in this manner, one of them being spring-cloud-circuitbreaker, which contains `<resilience4j.version>2.0.2</resilience4j.version>` among its props.

That resolves the question around where the value is coming from, but it does not explain why the version is not entirely overridden by resilience4j version that I specify in my pom. The resilience4j-vavr dependency uses the value that I specify, but its transitive dependencies do not.

When I download the spring-cloud-circuitbreaker pom and refer to it as the parent rather than via the dependencyManagement section, all of the resilience4j transitive dependencies use the resilience4j version that I specify, as expected.

Comment: Try running `mvn dependency:tree` on both scenarios, you will be able to see where the dependency is coming from.

Comment: Also check the documentation about the scope import. With it you are effectively asking maven to replace those dependencies to the ones being imported. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: @JorgeCampos `mvn dependency:tree` shows that resilience4j-ratelimiter is pulled in by resilience4j-vavr in both scenarios, but when dependencyManagement is included, it has a lower version.

Comment: Then I would say it is probably because of the `<version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>` + import scope. check what happens if in the dependencyManagement for spring cloud you add an exclusion for resilience4j-vavr.

Comment: I think you are right, but excluding resilience4j-vavr and/or resilience4j-ratelimiter does not prevent it from pulling in v2.0.2.

Comment: Yes so, your problem is exactly as stated. The `import` scope of the dependencyManagement section is forcing maven to override any dependency on your tree (outside of dependencyManagement section) with the dependencies (transitive or not) of the one annotated with the scope import. So if you go into the spring cloud 2022.0.4 tree you will see the resilience listed there to the version you don't want (2.0.2) here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2022.0.4 it gets the resilience bom which then gets its dependencies (click on it to see)

Comment: Ok that explains a lot. All of the resilience4j dependencies are included explicitly by the resilience4j-bom, which is brought in by spring-cloud-circuitbreaker. I am overriding the vavr dependency within my pom, which changes the version to the one that I specify, but all of the other resilience4j dependencies are still coming from the resilience4j-bom. That all makes sense to me now.

I still don't understand why excluding them in the dependencyManagement section as you suggested does not work.

Comment: Probably because I asked you to exclude the dependency in specific not the BOM, if you try to exclude the bom it might work